# Copying one file to many based on other file names and types

Tags: scripts, copy, xterm

I have a bunch of files named after a bunch of letters (c,f,s & w), e.g.: `cccf.png`, `fsws.png`, etc. There is also a file that I need to copy to match these names with a `[back]` in the name, e.g.: `cccf[back].png`, `fsws[back].png`, etc.

I have tried

```bsh
for file in ./????.png; do
  cp Back.png "$file"[back].png
done
```

which gave me `cccf.png[back].png`, `fsws.png[back].png`. While easy to do a mass rename in the gui (Xfce) to remove the `.png` in the middle, this seems a little redundant.

How do I only grab that part of the file name I need, i.e. the four letters, append the `[back]` and then retain the suffix, as I want to do this for many file types and not be restricted to `.png`.

To simplify, how do I copy a file so that the name inserts something into the middle of another name, leaving all files already there untouched?

Answer (score 3):

Use shell [parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) to

1. remove everything up to the (last, if the filename itself contains them) period and save the result as the extension

   ```
   ext="${file##*.}"
   ```
2. remove the extension, then add back the new suffix + extension

   ```
   backfile="${file%.*}[back].${ext}"
   ```

Ex.

```
file=cccf.png
ext="${file##*.}"
backfile="${file%.*}[back].${ext}"
echo "$backfile"
cccf[back].png
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for my purposes, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try that command this way:

```bsh
for f in ./*
do
  v="$(basename "$f")"
  cp Back.png "${v%%.*}"\[back\].png
done
```

Script Information:

- Use `v="$(basename "$f")"` to get thte filename names
- Use `cp Back.png "${v%%.*}"\[back\].png` to `copy` and create new file with the
        desired filename.
- The `${v%%.*}` captures just the part of the filename you need without the extension!